# RTCPeerConnection is not defined in Firefox 76.0.1

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

I was learning about WebRTC and came across this [demo app](https://webrtc-from-chat.glitch.me/) on MDN which does not work on my Firefox 76.0.1. The console error is : `ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined`. I tried to verify this by creating a new instance of `RTCPeerConnection` : `new RTCPeerConnection()` in the console and sure enough, it does not exist. It seems to be a firefox only issue. I did not get this error on other browsers. **Do I need to enable something in my browser in order to use this API?** I find it hard to believe that this API would not be suported by Firefox.

Oh, and it's not just `RTCPeerConnection`. None of the other peer connection APIs such as `RTCIceCandidate` are available either.

Comment: It's ll broken since about a year, it's about mDns and dot local adresses, see https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/ Fixes are possible, but all libraries get broken without TURN servers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the value of `media.peerconnection.enabled` in `about:config`. The default value is on but it might have been modified by an extension.